# FedEx Tracking API Response: 404

Tags: php, rest, fedex

Here is the situation.

I have a Rest API Tracking setup trying to get the status of the FedEx package.

Here is my code:

```
   $url = 'https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/track/v1/123456789012';

   $api = new App_ApiTransaction('POST', $url, '', App_ApiTransaction::ENCODE_JSON);
   $api->addHeader( 'Authorization', 'Bearer '.$accessToken->accessToken);
   $api->addHeader( 'X-locale', 'en_US');
   $api->addHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Why would I be getting a 404 response code?

Thank you,
Kevin

Comment: I think the URL in your example code should be between quotes. But that's just syntax. 

As far as  I know, 404 indicates not found, the URL is incorrect. Is not about wrong parameters or method or permissions.

Comment: The funny thing is this. I'm using the URL based on the documentation, https://www.fedex.com/api/en-us/catalog/track/v1/docs.html#operation/TrackingDocuments

Comment: Hi @Kevin, not sure if you've solved this, but the url of the testing environment is `https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services` if you're using SOAP, and `https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/xml` if you're using the plain XML web services solution. Also, the latest version of the tracking service is v19. More details can be found on the [FedEx Web Services Developer Guide](https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/webhelp/ws/2020/US/FedEx_WebServices_2020_Developer_Guide.htm#t=wsdvg%2FTracking_and_Visibility_Services.htm).